why are BLDC and PMSM eficiency and power curves different?
My understanding of BLDC and PMSM motors:
I understand: A permanent magnet synchronous motor(PMSM) is a type of brushless DC motor (BLDC).
They have different bEMF waveforms PMSM sinusoidal, and BLDC trapezoidal. my understanding is that is physically for the reason they are winded differently.
Now let's suppose I want to spin a BLDC and PMSM motor using FOC.
My understanding is that in a 3 phase motor, FOC makes the same torque regardles of the relative position of the rotor and stator. Because the resulting force form, the magnetic field is always tangent with the rotor. My understanding is that this is true for BLDC and PMSM motors alike.
Now the best mechanical power output for a BLDC is in somewhere in the middele of the maximum rpm with a set supply voltage. Max power rpms = Vcc*Kv/2 this is where the back emf is proportionally the same as the I^2R losses. this is represented by this curve

From experience and common calculations this operating point is not the best mode for efficiency not the best for torque not the best for rpm.
How come do some PMSM motors have a profile like this
Aren't these types of motors super similar? Why such drastic changes. This PMSM curve has a constant torque and power band. How do i achieve such improved efficiency at different rpms.
Can i drive a BLDC motor with FOC and get the "PMSM" curve? Is the driving method different?

Slovak Rocketry - Hi, Where did the images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY
